# How to make the kubernetes dashboard accessible through normal http?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment, kubernetes-dashboard

I am struggling with this since basically WEEKS now... There is literally not one single example how to do this on the whole internet. Its actually quiet hilarious.

My dashboard deployment:

```
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --namespace=kube-system
        - --enable-insecure-login
        - --insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0
        image: kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.3.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 9090
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 30
        name: kubernetes-dashboard
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsGroup: 2001
          runAsUser: 1001
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /certs
          name: kubernetes-dashboard-certs
        - mountPath: /tmp
```

**NOTE THE FOLLOWING:**

As of the official [Dashboard arguments documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/common/dashboard-arguments.md)

i added the arguments to the dashboard deployment :

```
--enable-insecure-login
```

which ENABLES INSECURE LOGIN: meaning a default port 9090 will available on the dashboard (the container i guess ).

As you can see i further made that very container accessible on the kubernetes pod itself

```
ports:
        - containerPort: 9090
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
```

after that,.. of course i also routed that very port in the service for the dashboard itself.

here is my service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"name":"kubernetes-dashboard","namespace":"kube-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":443,"targetPort":8443}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2022-04-05T13:11:22Z"
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "12795"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
  uid: 01bb1897-e18f-418e-949d-465069b561de
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.152.183.208
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.152.183.208
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30838
    port: 9090
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Here we can see beautifully that the ports are all correctly assigned:

```
- nodePort: 30838
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
```

The `nodePort` is optional.. it will be the port the service exposes all of this to the outside world (aka a browser etc.)

The `port` is the port that the service will internally inside the cluster be exposed. I have chosen to leave it at its default value.

Finally the `targetPort` must match the initially exposed port on the pod. And it does.

Of course i have set `--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0` inside the dashboard arguments to allow the insecure port to be served on any address.

When i try to access it with a browser, its just dead. No response, no nothing.

So where did i go wrong ?

Is there really no example ? If i manage to get this to work, i as a matter of fact plan to officially propose the SOLUTION to Kubernetes itself or some major tutorial services. I see literally hundreds of people struggling with this, giving up eventually etc. :D

Comment: there is probably no example because its a bad idea.

Comment: That does not mean its a bad question.

Comment: Could you elaborate a) why you want this and b) why you think this should be promoted, as it clearly is a bad idea from security point of view

Comment: First of all, it's not that bad of an idea if you decently secure the gateway. Rather than writing `kubectl port-forward` every single time, using a common url can be good for the team, but as I said, If you properly secure the gateway. Second of all, did you `inspect` the page, is the browser page getting any error? Also, is traffic coming the dashboard pod? What are the logs?
Also, you can use https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/master/aio/deploy/alternative this directory with changing service to `NodePort`. I haven't spot the problem you have  but we can figure it out I assume.